# Add/Subtract a single row to a cell reference

Tags: excel

I have an empty cell where I want my output to go. I am trying to add 1 row to cell $E$6. I want the output to say $E$7 (not the value in the cell). Vice versa, to subtract 1 row from cell $E$6 for the output to be $E$5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ADDRESS` function. The third argument should be "1" in your case, to get absolute references.

Comment: Could you please show how it will look like i.e. ADDRESS(6,5,1,1,?). Still now sure where the 'adding' value goes.

Comment: `=ADDRESS(ROW($E$6)+1,5,1)`. Hope that helps.